# limit point on real line

Tags: general-topology

Consider a subset $A=[a,b)$ of $\Re$. Than it is verified that every element in $[a,b)$ is a limit point of $A$. The point b is also a limit point of $A$.

This is not making sense to me though I could understand limit points for a discrete and small set as example. Can someone please elaborate on it?

Answer (score 4):

Let $\epsilon >0$. Let $x=b-\frac12\min (\epsilon,b-a)$. Then $x\in [a,b)$, $x\neq b$ and $|b-x|<\epsilon$.